# @@ROWCOUNT returns 0 when it should be 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, rowcount

The following function is causing me issues. It always falls into the `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` even when the `@Result` has a value in it. I have ran these statements in isolation outside the function to confirm that there is data and the rowcount is actually 1. Yet somehow, every time the `@@ROWCOUNT = 0` in the `IF`.

My collegues do not get this problem, only me. They are using SQL Server 2017 and I am using 2019. Also I wonder if it could be related to the speed of my machine vs others, ie. the number of threads etc.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [fnc_SomeFuncion]
(
    @Param1 varchar(100),
    @Param2 nchar(10)

)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result bigint

    SELECT @Result = v.Id
    FROM vSomeView v WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE v.X = @Param1 AND v.Y = 1 AND v.Z = @Param2

    -- PRINT @Result -- prints 1

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 -- should be 1 but is 0
        BEGIN
            ... -- always enters here
        END

    RETURN @Result -- this is a valid id but never gets returned
END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58952917/unexpected-rowcount-behavior-inside-an-udf-in-ms-sql-2019

Comment: Ahh yes, hadn't noticed the OP said 2019. Clearly this is the Scalar inlining at work. if you don't want to disable inlining across the database, then use `WITH INLINE = OFF` in the function's declartion (goes prior to the `AS BEGIN`).

Comment: And the relevant answer on that question is a pointer to update to SQL Server 2019 CU4 or later, which disables inlining if you use @@rowcount. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4538581/fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019